# Regex to Match and Replace " with '

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to replace the double quotes " with a single quote ' in the below string.

```
("2016-09-28T09:08:45.812145","50.12"),("2016-09-28T09:09:45.969154","50.13"),("2016-09-28T09:10:45.926659","50.14")
```

How would I use a regex expression to do this?

Comment: `str.replace(/\"/g, "'")`

Comment: Have a look at this question: [Replacing all occurrences of a string in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/replacing-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way you can do it:

```js
var s = '("2016-09-28T09:08:45.812145","50.12"),("2016-09-28T09:09:45.969154","50.13"),("2016-09-28T09:10:45.926659","50.14")';

console.log(s.replace(/"/g,"'"));
```

Note that the regular expression is fairly simple, the only important point being the `g` modifier (which is the global modifier, as remarked by Wiktor Stribiżew), so all matches are detected and not just the first one.

Comment: I'd avoid mixing up "greedy" and "global modifier". "Greedy" is used to describe quantifier behavior while `/g` just makes the regex engine advance its index upon a successful match to be able to find the next non-overlapping match.